# how to configure htaccess file if main controller resides in public folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I saw a near identical question to mine, but the accepted answer doesn't work for some reason.

My problem is that I cannot access index.php which sits inside a public folder. I have tried innumerable combinations and believe that it's in the correct folder -- the public folder.

The answer that didn't work was to make the ReWriteBase %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public. I did that but get an Index of. At least the public folder is not visible, however, so it feels like I'm getting close.

Any help is appreciated.

PS. I can see the application on my local machine with RewriteBase /projectname/public but the URL must include public or I get an Index of page. I want to be rid of the public portion and work off the root (domain name).

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Updated htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteBase` is supposed to be relative path from `DocumentRoot` not full path.

Here are 2 .htaccess you need to use:

**root/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* public/$0 [L]
```

**public/.htaccess:**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I must be doing something wrong. You are clearly an expert. I get the same Index of page, which includes the public folder. Would having the URL help?

Comment: That's very kind. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. The htaccess file is inside the public folder. URL = seabreezespa.com

Comment: The path is seabreezespa.com/app/core/ . I just noticed something odd, however. In the file manager at InMotionHosting, there is no + sign next to seabreezespa.com to expand the directory tree. The files are there, but there's no trigger to see the directories.  I'm not sure if it is impacting what's happening. Perhaps when I uploaded the files, something went wrong.

Comment: Let me know if I should delete and re-upload to test ?

Comment: I will delete the files and FTP again. Then, I will let you know. Thanks so much for taking the time to help!

Comment: I deleted the current files and re-uploaded. Same problem exists.  The error message @seabreezespa.com/public (Warning: require_once(../app/controllers/home.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/pamska5/public_html/seabreezespa.com/app/core/App.php on line 23)

Comment: I deleted the current files and re-uploaded. Same problem exists.  The error message @seabreezespa.com/public/ is that it can't find my Controller file (../app/controllers/home.php) because it doesn't exist @/home/pamska5/public_html/seabreezespa.com/app/core/App.php. That's right.  It isn't there. It lives @/app/controllers/home.php. I don't know why the code is looking there. My require_once code is: require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php'; The code is in App.php, which lives @app/core/App.php. If this path was wrong, it wouldn't work locally.

Comment: It now appears to be some PHP include problem. I can suggest a rule that will now show directory listing when you open `http://seabreezespa.com/` URL but this php problem is not a rewrite issue.

Comment: Update:  I am another step closer. The controller didn't load because the file name is Home.php, but the variable value was home.php.  I fixed that so now the site loads @seabreezespa.com/public. This is not what I want and the menu links do not work. Is this now an .htaccess issue? I will edit the question to include the updated htaccess file. Any solution?

Comment: I apologize, but I edited your answer and not my question (my first edit). The updated htaccess file matches your recommendation. I will not attempt to edit the incorrect edit to avoid another error.

Comment: Update:  Links working so the only issue is to remove public from the URL

Comment: Thank you. I will wait to hear from you.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works great at the root (seabreezespa.com), taking me to the home page. However, 'public' reappears in the URL when another page is requested (seabreezespa.com/public/about). Is it possible to eliminate 'public' from the URL entirely?

Comment: Please disregard the last comment. I need to check something else first.

Comment: FANTASTIC! DONE!  The 'public' part is now removed. It was appended to the end of my ASSET_ROOT constant. This works perfectly! Thank you very much!! Based on your determination and follow through in helping me, I can begin to understand why you have 376k points. You have been incredibly helpful. I plan to carefully review the regular expressions you used to understand how this works. Thank you again.

Comment: All is well that ends well. Nothing more satisfactory than solving a problem. Really glad it all worked out for you.